# Does Angulars default change detection evaluate all templates for changes?

Tags: javascript, angular

In an example of default change detection in [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) the function `changeUserName()` on a `HomeComponent` changes the `user.name` property on an object which is injected into a child component.

Does Angulars default change detection have to evaluate all component templates when the button that triggers `changeUserName()` is clicked, or does it somehow know that the function `changeUserName()` is linked to one template only?

Comment: `Angular has to be conservative and run all the checks every single time because the JavaScript language does not give us object mutation guarantees.` V.Savkin https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c

Comment: It looks tricky.  I was hoping Angular had some way of reflectively scanning the code base and figuring out what code / functions are responsible for triggering updates that are tied to specific templates.